# Python 3.4 Text formatting from print()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I'm going through all these questions and they are some major coding issues. Here I am just trying to prompt a user for a phrase and the output be something like:

```
Twas
 brillig
  and
   slithy
    toves
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
stringInput = str.split((input("Enter a phrase: ")))
print()

for wordPrint in stringInput:
    print(wordPrint)

print()
```

I can get it to print:

```
Twas
 brillig
 and
 slithy
 toves
```

with:

```
print(wordPrint, end='\n ')
```

Its only spaces the second line and not anything further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the spaces yourself. Here's one possible implementation:

```
for index, word in enumerate(stringInput):
    print(' '*index + word)
```

Comment: That worked, i'd been poking at it for a while now. I'm such a beginner, thank you!

Comment: I needed an explanation for why it worked so i figured that out on my own:  Empty space(' '= 1) times enumerated word, 1*0=no space 1*(0,'word1')= 0 spaces, 1*(1,'word2') = 1 space, 1*(2,'word2') = 2 spaces